# How can i use WKWebView instead of UIWebView in Xamarin Forms WebView(iOS)

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I'm working on mobile application development using Xamarin.Forms (PCL). I am using Xamarin WebView to render some web view contents and i'm getting performance issue in  iOS application. So, i have analyzed and found that the WKWebView will improve the performance.

How can i use WKWebView in Xamarin Forms WebView instead of UIWebView ? Is there any custom rendering available to do this?

Comment: No unfortunately there is not a renderer implementing the WKWebView, you will have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You can create custom renderer using WKWebView.

Please have a look below and this is ios renderer class of WebView:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace DemoApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

for more information [click here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/iOS/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs) .

Comment: Do you have any code snippet for mapping Xamarin.WebView with WKWebView?

Comment: @Karthik see below link, there is sample of hybrid web view which is use WKWebview
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView

Comment: @Karthik, Please accept my answer if it was helped you. So, it will helped others.

Comment: @PavanVParekh - This doesn't work for me. I set up a new project, and set the main page Content to a WebView to begin with and it works as expected. When I create a custom renderer (I've called it WebViewExt), with the code as you've included above (with CustomWebView and CustomWebViewRenderer replaced with my names, of course), I get a blank web view. Do I need to actually set the controller myself in the `OnElementChanged` override (via `SetNativeControl`)?